# Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import the file system module and running it in a browser.. This error always pops up
Here's my code

```js
import * as fs from ('fs');
```

Could someone please helpm me.. Thank you so much

Comment: Well the error message should be pretty clear, if you recognize what "top level of a module" means. The `import` cannot be inside of a function.

Comment: Its not in a function. It at the start of the js file itself

Comment: OK, is the JavaScript file being loaded as a module? (`type=module` in the `<script>` tag).

Comment: No.. Its just a normal app.js file

Comment: Well there you go. You can only use `import` from *module* files, which means you've told the browser explicitly that the type of the `<script>` is "module".

Comment: dont use the parenthesis, do this: `import * as fs from 'fs'`